# Как сделать так, чтобы локальные и глобальные координаты объекта совпали в Blender?

Tags: 3d, blender

Есть объект, его вращение, позиция были изменены, а теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы все локальные оси совпадали с глобальными. Вручную можно повращать и т. д., но было бы надёжнее и точнее программно сделать это, если такая функция есть.

Comment: Object/Apply или Ctrl-A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта, в зависимости от того, что вам нужно.

1. Если вам нужно повернуть объект так, чтобы его координаты обнулились - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> При этом сам меш (геометрия) вращается вместе с осями.
2. Если вам нужно сбросить координатные оси объекта, но сама геометрия чтобы осталась на месте - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Rotation. При этом сам меш (геометрия) остается на месте.